# SublimeREPL: Python - RUN Current File

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimerepl

With python script currently opened in SublimeText I'm choosing:

Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > RUN Current File

Sublime executes the script in a new **interactive** *REPL*[python] window (this window is still inside of Sublime).

After the python script execution is finished Sublime types:

***Repl Closed***

I now can start typing the python commands into this interactive window below "***Repl Closed***" message. But when I press an Enter key the editor simply advances to a new line when I expect it to Execute a line I just typed.
Please advise what key (if any) should be used to run typed command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, go to `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python` to start a new Python REPL. You can then use the commands in `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL` and `Transfer to REPL` to transfer and/or evaluate pieces of your code in the running interpreter. When that code is done running, the REPL stays open, allowing you to enter new commands as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What is the difference between Eval In Repl and Transfer to Repl?

Comment: @Sputnix "Eval" actually evaluates ("runs") the code in the REPL, while "Transfer" does just that - transfers the text over, but doesn't run it. Please read the [README](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) and [the docs](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/) for more information on this plugin.